# WPF: XamlWriter.Save saves "Run" inlines differently - with tags and without (as simple text)

Tags: wpf, xml, xamlwriter

Textblock have 3 run inlines. I need to save it to xml, and I use XamlWriter.Save for that, as the result I got this:

```
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia" >
            ABC
            <Run FontSize="13">DEF</Run>
            GHI
</TextBlock>
```

The problem is, that this xaml is parsed then as a pure xml without using wpf framework. To make the parser work correctly I have to ensure, that xaml is presented like this:

```
<TextBlock xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 FontSize="14" FontFamily="Georgia" >
            <Run>ABC</Run>
            <Run FontSize="13">DEF</Run>
            <Run>GHI</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

e.g. every inline is a separate tag. How can I do this? 
I looked through properties and settings of XamlWriter and Inlines collection, but couldn't find anything that corresponds to that.